# Notification message in widows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, notifications

I want display a message while the application is running and the message should go off automatically . I tried message box but a user action is required to close that box. That needs to be avoided.

Is there any option in Windows Phone 7 for doing this?

Comment: have you tried displaying the message in a separate thread and dismiss it after certain amount of time?

Comment: display message using which control? You mean display the message using message box and dismiss it via code?

Comment: yes, via the messageBox, and dismiss it through code after some time

Comment: but when the messagebox is on , the page is incative. Only after the messagebox is closed the contriol goes back to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ToastPrompt control from Coding4Fun

- http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Toast-Prompt-in-depth

Available in NuGet

Comment: is it good practice to use toast like notification inside the application ?.

Comment: you can style the toast however you like - it's a whole page overlay in xaml - so it doesn't have to look like a toast.